# NodeJS anonymous function within an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does the following not return `a and b'?

```
Staff.config = {
    a: 'a constant',
    b: (function(){
        return this.a + ' and b';
    })()
};

console.log(Staff.config) // { a: 'a constant', b: 'undefined and b' }
```

Comment: Check what `this` is in the IIFE.

Comment: you have to replace `this.a` with ̀Staff.config.a ̀

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant `TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined`?

Comment: `(function(){
        return this.a + ' and b';
    })()` is getting executed under the scope of `window`(_this refers to window_) and `window` does not have property `a` hence it is `undefined`. This will help: `var Staff = {};
Staff.config = {
  a: 'a constant',
  b: function() {
    return this.a + ' and b';
  }
};
console.log(Staff.config.b());`

Comment: Remove the IIFE to a normal function and see if value is different

Comment: @RayonDabre thanks for that, although I am on NodeJS so window but I do understand your point. I had hoped that by simply running `console.log(Staff.config)` I would see the output of `Staff.config.b()` so that I don't have to physically invoke it.

Comment: @simon-p-r Is there no way of have this invoke when I do a `console.log(Staff.config)`? If I have it as a normal function, I will need to do `Staff.config.b()` to get the desired output right?

Comment: Try returning function as value

Comment: You can't refer to `this` inside any code that is evaluated during the definition of an object and expect it to point to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `(function(){ return this.a + ' and b'; })()` is getting executed under the global scope(this refers to window in browser) and in your case, global context does not have property `a` hence it is undefined.

Easier solution would be using `function expression` as a value of `b` hence `Staff.config.b()` will return expected output.

```js
var Staff = {};
Staff.config = {
  a: 'a constant',
  b: function() {
    return this.a + ' and b';
  }
};
alert(Staff.config.b());
```

> You could achieve the same using `getter` which gets the value of a specific property

Try this:

```js
var Staff = {};
Staff.config = {
  a: 'a constant',
  get b() {
    return this.a + ' and b';
  }
};
alert(Staff.config.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got an undefined is related to where the object properties are hoisted. First you are trying to reference an object property which is not yet allocated in the memory, so Javascript cannot point to a memory address, because that memory address is not yet allocated. This is the reason why you are getting an undefined on

```
return this.a + ' and b';
```

Here `this` is referencing to the `window` object, which is a global object. In Javascript each object is extended from the global `Object` or `window` in the case if Javascript is running in a browser.

Second you are trying to invoke a function by using the `Self Invoking method`, but this is always running in it's own scope, which means you cannot access a variable outside of it's own scope, at least if you do not wrap it to it's own context. Something like:

```
(function(closer) {
//...
})(scope)
```

This is what is called a closure.

So back to your original problem. If you construct your object in the following way it will work. This is because you are referring to properties of already instantiated object.

```
var Staff = Staff || {};

Staff.config = function() {
  this.a = "a constant";
  this.b = this.a + " and b";    
}

var staff = new Staff.config();
console.log(staff);
```